# universal link goes to safari instead of the app that called it

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I have a working universal link that works when used by another app. eg. if I write the link in notepad it will open app the app. But when I call the following inside the app that the universal link links to, it will open in safari. canOpenURL returns true.

have set up this `.well-known/apple-app-site-association` and also the correct `intent-filter`. I think its working because the links open the app when clicked outside of the app.

```
let url = Foundation.URL(string: "https://workingdeeplink.com/")!
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
```

Comment: When you already have the deeplink url inside the app that handles those deeplinks why do you want to try to trigger the univeral link flow. Deeplinking ‘delivers’ a URL using which an app has been launched. You already have that URL. So why do you want to use the openURL method here..?

Comment: Due to the reason above, the openURL method ‘will’ launch your app’s universal links in the browser. That is the intended behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. When an app passes its own universal link to `open`, iOS will open that link in Safari.

The purpose of this is to allow a fallback when an app cannot handle an incoming link.  The logic for handling an incoming link is typically something like:

1. Parse the incoming link
2. Determine if the app can handle it
3. If it can, then handle the link (e.g. select a specific view or take some action)
4. If it can't, pass the link to `open` so that the user is redirected back to the web site, where the link can be handled.

This avoids the situation where a deep link opens your app and then nothing happens or an error is shown (because the app can't handle the url)

There shouldn't be a case where your app tries to `open` a deep link it can handle; it can simply bypass then whole deep link process and take the action that would result directly.

Comment: By "bypass the whole deep link process" what do you mean? For instance, I am on a React-based cordova app and I am in the exact same scenario as OP. When I am viewing a PDF within my app, and I click a link to our website, which is deep-linked, iOS opens the link in Safari instead of going to the app. Are you suggesting I intercept the link upon clicking it and then route the user manually?

Comment: If you are showing that pdf in a web view, then yes, you need to use the web view delegate to recognise the link that is being navigated to, identify that it is a route your app can handle and navigate in your app directly.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem occurred because file `.well-known/apple-app-site-association` (AASA) was not downloaded.

Apple documentation says: (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains):

> When a user installs your app, the system attempts to download the
> associated domain file and verify the domains in your entitlement.

It seems sometimes the file isn't dowloaded for any reason. You can validate if AASA file was successfully downloaded using MAC Console app and filtering console output by "swcd" process (shared web credential daemon).

If the AASA downloaded sucessfully, you'll see activities of swcd process. If the AASA did not download, you must uninstall the app, restart the device, and then reinstall the app (in my case I uninstalled app for several times).

Find the detailed instructions here: https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/ios-troubleshooting#validate-if-aasa-file-successfully-downloaded